# How do I change the text of a jquery popup dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to change the text of a popup dynamically. I thought it might be something like this:

```
$("#mypopup").text("Loading...");
$("#mypopup").popup("open");
load();
$("#mypopup").text("Loaded!");
```

This means that the popup text would be "Loading.." until after the function load() finished. Then it would be "Loaded!"

I've tried this, among many other different approaches, none of which worked.

Could someone help me through this?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**
Sorry everyone, I forgot to mention I was using jQuery Mobile.

Here's more info http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Comment: What does popup("open") do ?
And what does load() do ?

Comment: What's `load()`? I'm guessing this is an async issue. Try looking into "async callbacks"

Comment: Your selector is _wrong_ `$("mypopup")`, surely you don't have `<mypopup>` element in your page.

Comment: @undefined Sorry, I meant to use "#mypopup" That was a typo, but not the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One** of the ways to change content of a `popup`

Given that you have a markup like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a id="btn2" href="#popup" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" data-rel="popup">Open a popup</a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popup" data-overlay-theme="a">
            <h1>It's a popup</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can handle `popupbeforeposition` and/or `popupafteropen` event

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function(){
    $("#popup").on("popupbeforeposition", function(event, ui) {
        $(this).append("<p>I've been added to popup!</p>");
    });
    $("#popup").on("popupafteropen", function(event, ui) {
        $(this).append("<p>It has been added after I'm open!</p>");
    });
});
```

**Another** approach would be create(or change) popup's content in a `click` event

Given the markup

```
<a id="btn1" href="#" data-role="button" data-transition="flip">Dynamic popup</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popup2" data-overlay-theme="e">
</div>
```

you can do

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#popup2").html("<h1>Header</h1><p>This is the popup's message.</p>").popup("open");
});
```

**UPDATE:**
And finally you can put it all together:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
   $.mobile.loading('show', {theme:"e", text:"Loading the content...", textonly:true, textVisible: true});
    setTimeout(function(){
        //Do some lengthy work here
        doWork();
        //Show the popup
        $("#popup2").html("<h1>Header</h1><p>This is the popup's message.</p>").popup("open");
    }, 50);
});
$("#popup2").on("popupafteropen", function(event, ui) {
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
});
```

**UPDATE2**:
Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/gH6xf/) to illustrate some lengthy work

Comment: I'm trying to change the contents of the popup AFTER it's opened, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: Just handle another event `popupafteropen`

Comment: `$.mobile.loading('show', {theme:"e", text:"Loading the content...",  itextonly:true, textVisible: true});`isn't running until after the function :\

Comment: The load() function still runs first :\. The loading popup is just delayed an extra 50 ms.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23069/discussion-between-peterm-and-areke)

Comment: @areke see the updated answer and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/gH6xf/). It simulates lengthy work