# $.mobile.changePage with role popup in Jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to have data role as popup in changePage with Jquery Mobile.

I am trying the following code

```
$.mobile.changePage('Last.html',{
            transition : 'slide',
                        role : 'popup'
});
```

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the documentation http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/ ? From what I know the answer to your question is *no*.

Comment: There is a open() method for the popup object : http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#method-open

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately from your question it's not clear why you need this.

Nevertheless, according to the jQM 1.2.0 documentation:

> To create a popup, add the data-role="popup" attribute to a div with
>   the popup contents. Then create a link with the href set to the id of
>   the popup div, and add the attribute data-rel="popup" to tell the
>   framework to open the popup when the link is tapped. This is a similar
>   markup pattern to the dialog widget. **A popup div HAS to be nested
>   inside the same page as the link.**

So you may not be able address external page (`Last.html`)

What you can do though:

1. create appropriate markup for a popup in your jQM page
2. if needed you can manipulate the content of your popup programmatically using  `popupbeforeposition` and/or `popupafteropen`
3. open a popup with `popup("open")` method

Here you can find [one of the examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431100/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-jquery-popup-dynamically).